# Create a list of users with status pictures

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select

I want to make a list of users and have an image indicating their online status but I have been unable to find a suitable option to do so with regular html select tags. I also want to be able to have options for each user, but that is not a problem for me.

I have created an image to help visualize what I am trying to get it, if my explanation isn't very good. I want to be able to change the picture/status indicator on the fly (without refreshing the page or doing something client-side).

Is there a way to set a picture for each user if the userlist isn't hardcoded into the html? (The users will be put into the list from database queries)

Note: I am using Node.js and socket.io for the online part of this, if that helps.

Picture for reference:

[image]

Edit: JSFiddle of similar design of userlist from the website I am working on (can't link directly to site, it's not an externally connected server): http://jsfiddle.net/Blubberguy22/LN45a/28/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="usersOptions" style="background-color: #ddeeff; left: 0; top: 0; position:absolute; 
height:260px; width:230px; border-style:inset; 
border-width: 0px; margin: 0; z-index: 300; "> <strong>Users Online:</strong>

        <select id='userList' style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" multiple></select>
        <button id='makeFakeUser' onclick="addUser();">AddUser</button>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
function addUser() {
    //In actual code gets users from connections within socket.io
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "A person";
    userList.add(option);
}
```

Just to clarify, I don't need help with getting the online status of the users, but with putting the status indicators next to them in the list.

Comment: Could you post a JSFiddle of what you have tried please so we can edit that to suit your needs/push you in the right direction.

Comment: Look for AJAX. You can query the server for online status (without page refresh) and use javascript to update the GUI indication.

Comment: I edited my original post to include a JSFiddle of what I have right now.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution here seems like it would be to have each client create a WebSocket to the server and have the server send an event whenever a user comes online or goes offline.

To actually change the image, you could do something like this:

```
joesNumber=22;
WebSocket.onmessage=function(event){
    data=JSON.parse(event.data);
    //Interpret data here
    document.getElementsByClassName("onlineIndicator")[joesNumber].src="./fancyIndicatorImage.png.jpg";
}
```

Comment: Would this work with an html-select tag? I already have the code setup and working for the online status retrieval, but I can't find a good way to set the picture.

Comment: @Blubberguy22 You would need to have an image inside each user's tag (`option.text = "<img src='fancyIndicator.gif.bmp' class='onlineIndicator'>A person";`), but you'll need that regardless of which solution you use.    
    
Just FYI, you'll probably want two images (for offline and online) that you can switch between.

Comment: That doesn't work. I think option elements only support basic text. It just displays as `<img src='picture.jpg'>`.